# Index some rows with date range in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a dataframe that is indexed by dates (year and time till seconds) and I would like to get the rows that correspond to a specific period of time I compute. However, I am not able to get rid of the keyerror when indexing with datetime type or str type. The code is like the following:

```
def get_series(self, id_dataset, time=None):
    if time == None:
        time = dt.datetime.now()
    time = time.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

    dataframe_global = pandas.read_csv('../rsc/datasets/' + str(id_dataset).replace(":", "_") + '.csv',
                                       delimiter=',')

    dataframe_global['timestamp_index'] = pandas.to_datetime(dataframe_global['timestamp'])
    dataframe_global = dataframe_global.set_index('timestamp_index')
    # dataframe_global = pandas.read_csv('../rsc/datasets/historic4.csv', delimiter=',')

    previous_measures = []
    for diff in self.difference_times:
        time1 = last_time - dt.timedelta(minutes=(diff - 30))
        time2 = last_time - dt.timedelta(minutes=(diff + 30))

        ind = str(time2.isoformat(sep=' '))
        ind2 = str(time1.isoformat(sep=' '))
        prev = dataframe_global[ind:ind2]
```

The Keyerror appears in the last line of code.

Values:

last_time = datetime(2018-07-04 16:55:59.02000)

time = datetime(2018-07-04 17:09:59.02000)

time2 = datetime(2018-07-04 16:39:59.02000)

ind = '2018-07-04 16:39:59.02000'

in2 = '2018-07-04 17:09:59.02000'

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try using the .iloc function

Comment: I have jus tried and i have the same errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Your indexers are likely defined incorrectly. We can't tell for sure because you haven't included `last_time` or `ind` / `ind2` values.

Remember that if you construct a `datetime` index from only a `Timestamp`, today's date will be used, since a `datetime` object must specify both date and time. Below is a demo. It may be sufficient to use `ind = str(time2)` and `ind2 = str(time1)` directly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
                  index=['00:00:00', '20:10:20', '12:15:00'])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

today = pd.to_datetime('today').date()
start_time = '10:00:00'
end_time = '22:00:00'

res = df[f'{today} {start_time}': f'{today} {end_time}']

print(res)

                     0  1  2
2018-09-12 20:10:20  3  4  5
2018-09-12 12:15:00  6  7  8
```

Comment: added values of the variables